# org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl cannot be cast to a class in spring roo

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-roo

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String create(@Valid Standup standup, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Principal principal, Employee employee) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        populateEditForm(uiModel, standup);
        return "standups/create";
    }

    uiModel.asMap().clear();


    String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

    Employee empByName = (Employee) Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(name);

    System.out.println(empByName.getName());
    standup.persist();
    return "redirect:/standups/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(standup.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

that is the portion of my code. Everything works fine just except the line where I'm trying to create an employee by finding it by it's name. Employee is an active record class and the finder is default. I've just added it.

The error says:

```
org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.example.standupmanager.domain.Employee
```

and the stack trace:

```
com.example.standupmanager.web.StandupController.create(StandupController.java:44)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

And I'm adding the content of employee finder code that is automatically generated by roo.

```
 public static TypedQuery<Employee> Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(String name) {
        if (name == null || name.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name argument is required");
        EntityManager em = Employee.entityManager();
        TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Employee AS o WHERE o.name = :name", Employee.class);
        q.setParameter("name", name);
        return q;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the method 'findEmployeesByNameEquals' return an object of type Employee? or perhaps a Collection of Employees? can you include your hibernate.cfg.xml as well?

Comment: can u share the code for Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(String )

Comment: Hi ye9ane, deepak thanks for replying.
   public static TypedQuery<Employee> Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(String name) {
        if (name == null || name.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name argument is required");
        EntityManager em = Employee.entityManager();
        TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Employee AS o WHERE o.name = :name", Employee.class);
        q.setParameter("name", name);
        return q;
    }
    

This is the finder code that is auto generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `findEmployeesByNameEquals` is returning the Query object, but your Controller is expecting the method to return the **result** of the query.  Try changing your method to execute the query and return the result:

```
public static Employee findEmployeesByNameEquals(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name argument is required");
    EntityManager em = Employee.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Employee AS o WHERE o.name = :name", Employee.class);
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: @HasanIqbal Glad I could help Hasan!

Answer (score 1):

If Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals is auto generated code; most probably you will be reluctant to modify it.
Modify 
Employee empByName = (Employee) Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(name);

to

```
Employee empByName = (Employee) Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(name).getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `TypedQuery<Employee> Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(String name)` returns a TypedQuery which you can't cast directly to your domain objects,but instead can add this line after the method is called:

```
TypedQuery<Employee> q = Employee.findEmployeesByNameEquals(name);
List<Employee> res = q.getResultList();
for(Employee employee : res){
      // do something here;
}
```

hope it helps.